# Invalid ModelState with PartialViews

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, partial-views, t4mvc

I have the following action

```
[GET("Foo")]
public virtual ActionResult Foo()
{
    return View(new FooViewModel());
}
```

the view for this action calls this partial view

```
@{ Html.RenderAction(MVC.FooBar.AddFoo()); }
```

with controller actions

```
[ChildActionOnly]
[GET("Foo/Add")]
public virtual ActionResult AddFoo()
{
    var viewModel = new AddFooViewModel();

    return PartialView(viewModel);
}

[POST("Foo/Add")]
public virtual ActionResult AddFooPost(AddFooViewModel viewModel)
{
    // If ModelState is invalid, how do I redirect back to /Foo 
    // with the AddFooViewModel ModelState intact??
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return MVC.FooBar.Foo();

    // ... persist changes and redirect
    return RedirectToAction(MVC.FooBar.Foo());
}
```

If somebody submits the AddFoo form with ModelState errors, I want the POST action to redirect back to /Foo and show the AddFoo partial view with the ModelState errors. What's the best approach to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up putting the viewmodel into `TempData` like this with the `ModelStateToTempData` attribute on the controller

```
[ChildActionOnly]
[GET("Foo/Add")]
public virtual ActionResult AddFoo()
{
    var viewModel = TempData["AddFooViewModel"] as AddFooViewModel ?? new AddFooViewModel();

    return PartialView(viewModel);
}

[POST("Foo/Add")]
public virtual ActionResult AddFooPost(AddFooViewModel viewModel)
{
    // If ModelState is invalid, how do I redirect back to /Foo 
    // with the AddFooViewModel ModelState intact??
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        TempData["AddFooViewModel"] = viewModel;
        return RedirectToAction(MVC.FooBar.Foo());
    }

    // ... persist changes and redirect
    return RedirectToAction(MVC.FooBar.Foo());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could achieve that in 2 ways:

1. Using session state
2. Passing your data using querystring params

I prefer the second option.